# A proxy php script for one website

Tags: php, proxy

I'm looking for something that I'm not sure it exist.
If not I'm happy to get directions to do it.

I rent a proxy from a proxy company, so I have an IP, username and password to use it.

I would like to put those informations in a php script, then be able to surf through the proxy using this php script.

This will give me the opportunity to give the link to other person without them to have to change the config in them browser.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't use Apache + mod_proxy to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may be what you are looking for

http://freshmeat.net/projects/phpproxy/

Do a search in Google for PHP Proxy, there are many for your needs.

Comment: It's what I'm looking for but that one doesn't support proxy authentification, and the client need to run a python script. I would like the client to just click on the link and the server does the rest.  

My target is to do like that : http://www.daveproxy.co.uk/, but instead of using my own server as a proxy, it's to use the other proxy that i'm renting.